# Overwrite value while from For Each

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, foreach

I am iterating a collection with For Each.
Everytime I find a string, ending with ";", I need to remove that ";".
(It is used for csv-parsing, and I have a bogus file from third party).

When I identify a line, I want it to overwrite the existing value of e.g. "12;" with "12".

This piece of code finds all the right lines, but no overwrite in the arrAccounts.

```
dim con
For Each con In arrAccounts(x)
    if Right(con,1) = ";" then
        dim length
        length =  Len(con)
        con = Left(con, (length-1))
    end if
next
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `output = Replace(input, ";", "")` to remove the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing is that you have to insert the new value into the array again.

```
dim i, con
for i = 0 to ubound(arrAccounts(x)) ''# for keeping track which item we are looking at
    con = arrAccounts(x)(i)
    if right(con, 1) = ";" then
        con = left(con, len(con) - 1)
        arrAccounts(x)(i) = con ''# insert the new value back into the array at the same position
    end if
next
```

Comment: You are spot on, and I figured it out just before. The problem was writing to a local variable instead of the passed-in parameter.